# Is there a way to keep my React JS PWA (Progressive Web App) running in background?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, background

I coded a Chatting App and a Alarm clock App in React Js and they're working fine in foreground *(while the apps are opened on screen)*. But I need a way to keep them running in the background to check for latest messages or to play the alarm sound. *(Like clock app in phone or WhatsApp/Facebook)*

**Does anyone has solution?**

I can't seem to find any solution, either by myself or Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting mobile devices, the best solution you have is to run a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), which can execute code in the background and show notifications. There are limits to the APIs available to a service worker, so playing a sound might not be possible.

Comment: I have a service worker which I use to show a offline page in my app. Can you guide me  more how can I run my functions from the Home.js file through that sw.js file.

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for: https://pwa-workshop.js.org/6-background-sync/#background-synchronization
You'd check for new content and display a notification if applicable. A timer app is the worst case however, because you have no guarantee of when it will run. Try finding code examples that do what you want to do and adapt them, SW are still under-documented.